# i am trying to extract day from date in laravel but running into this error A two digit year could not be found Data missing

Tags: laravel

i am trying to fetch day from date using laravel
but i am running in to this error A two digit year could not be found Data missing
here is my query

```
$tb=DB::table('attandancesheets')->select('id','code','employee','start_time','end_time',
         'ispresent','isweekend','total_hours','date',"date as day"+Carbon::createFromFormat('y-m-d','date')->format('l'),
        )->orderBy('date','asc')->get();
```

i am also trying to use like this but getting this error

```
 $tb=DB::table('attandancesheets')->select('id','code','employee','start_time','end_time',
         'ispresent','isweekend','total_hours','date',"date as day"+\DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "date"),
        )->orderBy('date','asc')->get();
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL you should use [`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) as a [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions) or convert the date **after** you get the results from the database

Comment: how i can do this ? i am learner any example ?

Comment: Replace `"date as day"` with `\DB::raw("DAYNAME(date) as day")` and remove the `Carbon` reference after it

Comment: thanks it working like a charm thanks

Comment: You should mark as resolved then